# Avoiding redundant work when matching and parsing

Tags: rust

I'm using `match` to see if string input is a position, and if it does, convert it to a tuple. For example, "B6" would become (1, 5). I have the functions `is_pos` to math the right input and `parse_pos` to transform it, so each `match` needs to perform string parsing twice.

```
fn main() {
    let input = ""
    match input {
        "exit" => return,
        _ if is_pos(input) => parse_pos(input),
        _ => (0, 0),
    };
}

fn is_pos(str: &str) -> bool {
    // string processing
    true
}

fn parse_pos(str: &str) -> u32 {
    // the same string processing
    5
}
```

I'd to have one function that returns an `Option`. Then the match would select the `Option` if it wasn't none, and I could unwrap it without needing to redo the string parsing.

Is this possible with `match`, or should I go back to using if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no elegant way to save the intermediate result of the `if` clause. Yes you could go back to an `if` statement.

```
if input == "exit" {
    return;
}
let pos = parse_pos(input).unwrap_or((0, 0));
```

You could still use a `match` like this:

```
let pos = match input {
    "exit" => return,
    _ => parse_pos(input).unwrap_or((0, 0)),
};
```

(Note that the early-return here does not really stand out. Could be a problem for future readers.)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with your second option. As long as I don't add any more options, it works fine.

Comment: Interestingly, Rust doesn't even allow you to "cheat" by writing a `parse_pos()` that explicitly saves the parsed data to the provided reference (and returns bool to work as an if inside match). The invocation is rejected by the compiler with ["cannot borrow mutably in a pattern guard"](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ba15518624b85712cf34eb30b74fbbca&version=stable&backtrace=0). I wonder why this restriction is in place.

Comment: @user4815162342 [E0301](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0301) explained it. You could still use a Cell to workaround it.

Comment: @kennytm Thanks. It's a good explanation, it really pays to read the detailed message.

Comment: @user4815162342: A lot of work has been put in the compiler errors; not only the error messages themselves (both content and formatting) but also the additional explanations provided by `--explain` or available on the page linked to. If you have issues understanding an error, I really encourage you to check the detailed message. And if the detailed message is not enough, or you have an idea for either the compiler message or the detail message, please speak up :)